# Concatenation with Null in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, concatenation

I have a simple code below.

```
Select columnA, columnB, columnC
  From table.
```

Here is my result.

```
ColumnA  ColumnB  ColumnC
Apple    G        null
Juice    S        T9
```

Now, I use the concatenation as follow

```
Select 
  ColumnA + '_'+ ColumnB + '_' + ISNULL(ColumnC, '') as Name
  From table
```

My output is as below

```
Name
Apple_G_
Juice_S_T9
```

How do I modify the concatenation above so it would show as Apple_G instead of Apple_G_
Basically, I have an extra _ from my result.

Comment: The `COALESCE()` or `ISNULL()` functions or conditions could help. When the `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` option is ON, you have to handle `NULL` values manually. It is always recommended to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Just concatenate the underscore with the nullable column before you apply the `IsNull` function.

```
Select 
  ColumnA + '_'+ ColumnB + ISNULL('_' + ColumnC, '') as Name
  From table
```

This requires the [`CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx) option being set to ON. - Which it is by default and which is very strongly recommended by Microsoft.

Comment: I was just about to write this very same thing.

Comment: Would that work no matter what `ANSI_NULLS` is set to? I think I remember there's a setting in which `x + null <> null`...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: ANSI_NULLS = OFF allows for equality comparison with NULL. E.g. `WHERE Something = NULL`.  However, I added an info on CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL which probably is what you were remembering.

Answer (score 0):

Use either `IIF` (SQL Server 2014+) or `CASE`:

**`IIF`**

```
Select 
    ColumnA + '_' + 
    ColumnB + 
    IIF(ColumnC IS NOT NULL, '_' + ColumnC, '')
From table
```

**`CASE`**

```
Select 
    ColumnA + '_' + 
    ColumnB + 
    CASE 
        WHEN ColumnC IS NOT NULL THEN '_' + ColumnC
        ELSE ''
    END
From table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use COALESCE that it will return the first not null expression

```
Select COALESCE(ColumnA + '_'+ ColumnB + '_' + ColumnC, ColumnA + '_'+ ColumnB) as Name
  From table
```

or if you want to customize it in a deeper level

```
Select COALESCE(ColumnA + '_'+ ColumnB + '_' + ColumnC, 
                ColumnA + '_'+ ColumnB,
                ColumnA ) as Name
  From table
```

The whole solution relies to the SQL server feature that if any of the concatenated strings is null the complete string becomes null.

Comment: +Mr. Vergis, very useful techniques. Thanks a lot

Comment: Is `x + null == null` always? I think I remember there's a setting where this is not the case...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Yes, there is a setting to change this default behavior but I have never encounter any DB with this setting turned off.